# getting material-ui TextField value onsubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to get the value of TextField input and render the message conditionally. I tried this one, its working but this one is functioning dynamically because I used `onChange`. I want to achieve the same but using `onSubmit` on `<Button>` Is there anyway to do that?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
class App extends Component 
{ 
    state = { 
        myValue: null, 
    } 
 
    handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ 
        myValue: e.target.value 
    }) 
     
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
            <TextField 
                value={this.state.myValue} 
                onSubmit={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button  >Get Weather</button>
            {this.state.myValue ? <p>value inputed </p>: <p>no input</p>}
            
            </div>

        ) 
    } 
} 


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is what you need. You can get the current value of your input by clicking a button and only then change the state.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-ref-to-mui-textinput-class-component-3qyqq?file=/src/App.js:0-701)

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = createRef();
    this.state = {
      myValue: ""
    };
  }
  showRefContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      myValue: this.textInput.current.value
    });
  };

  handleChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({
      myValue: e.target.value
    });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField inputRef={this.textInput} />
        <button onClick={this.showRefContent}>Get Weather</button>
        <p>
          {this.state.myValue.length > 0
            ? `text:${this.state.myValue}`
            : "no text"}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to you onkeydown instead onsubmit.

```
<TextField 
            value={this.state.myValue} 
            onKeyDown={this.handleChange}
        />
```

or use

```
<form onSubmit={handleChange }>
  <TextField 
                value={this.state.myValue} 
                onKeyDown={this.handleChange}
            />
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: onKeyDown will update the state after each typed letter and that's exactly the opposite behaviour OP wants.